# Wait for angular to render an element after socket connect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sockets, socket.io, render

I want to trigger a function when, there is a successful socket `connect` and when `angular` has rendered the element.

```
Ex. <canvas id="{{currentUserId}}"></canvas>
```

I want following in my code:

```
socket.on('connect',function(){
  until(<above canvas is present>)
    callMe();
});
```

Comment: Can you add `callback` to function that calls `socket`?

Comment: socket.on('connect',...) is an event, so it wont be called by some function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library :

```
socket.on('connect',function(){
    async.until(
      function(){
        return $('#canvasId').length > 0;
      },
      async.ensureAsync(
        function(retry){
        console.log('trying');
        retry(null,null);
        }
      ),
      function(err,result){
        console.log('rendered');
        callMe();
      }
    );
  });
```

Following is the explanation:

```
async.until(test,async.ensureAsync(fn),callback){}

test : return true/false, if returns false fn will be called and this will repeat until true is returned and on that final callback is called

fn: do some action, for my case I just wanted to wait, so I am not performing any action

async.ensureAsync(fn) : ensures that one fn is called in one tick and prevents stack overflow if there are too many attempts

callback: is called when test returns true
```